# What is the type of an async function action in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, async-await, react-redux

Got a question about type for React w/ Redux coupled with redux-thunk.

I have an async actions where I dispatch actions depending of my API response like so :

```
export const myAsyncAction = (id: string) => {
  return async (dispatch: Dispatch<{}>) => {
    // Dispatch REQUEST Action
    dispatch(loadRequest())

    const response = await get(`api/something/${id}`)
    if (!response.ok) {
      // Dispatch the FAILURE action
      dispatch(loadFailure('error'))
    } else {
      const json = await response.json()
      // Dispatch the SUCCESS action
      dispatch(loadSuccess(normalize(json, mySchema)))
    }
  }
}
```

(Please let me know if this action doesn't look right for you as well)

And then in my Component I am declaring this interface for the `mapDispatchToprops` :

```
interface IComponentMapDispatchToProps {
  myAsyncAction: (id: string) => Promise<any>
}

interface IComponentProps
  extends IComponentMapDispatchToProps {
}

export class Component extends React.Component<IComponentProps, {}> {

  render() {
    return <div>Whatever</div>
  }
}

const mapDispatchToprops: IComponentMapDispatchToProps = {
  myAsyncAction
}

export default connect(
  {},
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Component)
```

Now typescript is complaining about the `mapDispatchToProps` saying this :

```
Type '() => (dispatch: Dispatch<{}>) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '() => Promise<any>'.
  Type '(dispatch: Dispatch<{}>) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<any>'.
    Property 'then' is missing in type '(dispatch: Dispatch<{}>) => Promise<void>'.
```

Now I thought that the type of an `async` function was a `Promise<{}>` type and here it's complaining about the fact that it's not...

And if I inject this async action in another component that has `withRouter` coupled with `connect` then I can type it like this and typescript is suddenly happy :

```
interface IComponentMapDispatchToProps {
  myAsyncAction: () => Promise<void>
}

export default withRouter(
  connect(
    {},
    mapDispatchToprops
  )(Component)
)
```

How can the same function can have different type depending of where it's called !?

What is the correct type for this async function ? because this doesn't make sense to me anymore.

Comment: myAsyncAction is a function that returns a function that returns a promise.. So its type is `(id: string) => (dispatch: Dispatch<{}>) => Promise<void>`

Comment: It still complaining unfortunately with `Types of property 'myAsyncAction' are incompatible.`
          `Type '() => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '() => (dispatch: Dispatch<{}>) => Promise<void>'.`
            `Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type '(dispatch: Dispatch<{}>) => Promise<void>'.`
              `Type 'Promise<void>' provides no match for the signature '(dispatch: Dispatch<{}>): Promise<void>'.`

Comment: It looks like that my `mapDispatchToProps` type is what causing the problem... if I do `const mapDispatchToprops = { myAsyncAction }` instead of `const mapDispatchToprops: IComponentMapDispatchToProps = {myAsyncAction}` everything works as it should be.. Still have a lot to learn about Typescript... Thanks @yaba for correcting me with the type, it does make sense now !